# Exact criteria match in a Arrayformula

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I have a formula that work perfectly in google sheet except that the criteria in the `sumif` sections have to be case sensitive match.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A:A="Account ID","Total",SUMIF('Report'!C2:C,A:A,'Report'!E2:E)+SUMIF('Report'!$B$2:$B,A:A,'Report'!$E$2:$E)))
```

I've try with EXACT and FIND but couldn't figure out how to make it work

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 0):

Use FILTER, like this:

```
=MAP(A:A,LAMBDA(ζ,IF(ζ="Account ID","Total",SUM(FILTER(Report!E2:E,EXACT(Report!B2:B,ζ)+EXACT(Report!C2:C,ζ))))))
```